# Build and deploy ASP.NET MVC app that is in a solution with other apps

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Have a Visual Studio 2017 solution that contains an MVC web app, a few class libraries, but also a web api project.  I want to setup a build and deploy the web app to my test server.  In my release, where can I tell it to only use the web app to deploy with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `/t:{projectname}` additional argument in **MSBuild Arguments** of **Visual Studio Build** task.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

In the Solution Explorer go to your Web app project. Right click and choose "Publish".  This will allow you to pick a publish target for your web project (and included references).

If your web app has a reference to the API project it will also be deployed. So remove that reference first. (And run your web app to see if it still builds)

Comment: I think maybe you are thinking about publishing via VIsual Studio, whereas I am trying to configure an automated build and deploy via Team Services (VSTS).